# List Comprehension with Python, classifying float to string

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to turn floats in a list into states of 'crisis', 'downturn' and 'susceptible' by following the three conditions. Is there a simpler, list comprehension way to do this? Or even map?

```
sector_g = np.random.randn(100) # 1 sector growth rates
sector_epi_states = [] #sector states

for i in range(0,100):
    if sector_g[i] <0 and sector_g[i-1] <0 and sector_g[i] != sector_g[0]:
        sector_epi_states.append('crisis')
    elif sector_g[i] <0:
        sector_epi_states.append('downturn')
    elif sector_g[i] >0:
        sector_epi_states.append('sucpetible')
```

Comment: Just write a function that takes a number and returns the correct string. Then apply the function in a comprehension, or use `map`.

Comment: This `sector_g[i] <0 and sector_g[i-1] <0` compares the first entry  at index `0` with last at index `-1` for ì = 0`. Is this intended?

Comment: No, thank you! Just amended the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code -

```
import numpy as np

sector_g = np.random.randn(100) # 1 sector growth rates
sector_epi_states = [] #sector states    
sector_epi_states = [ 'crisis' if (sector_g[i] < 0 and sector_g[i-1] < 0) else
                     'downturn' if sector_g[i] < 0 else 
                     'sucpetible' if sector_g[i] > 0 else ''
                     for i in range(0,100) ] #sector states
print(sector_g)
print(sector_epi_states)
```

Comment: Thank you! So much neater! Any documentation on list comprehension you can recommend?

Comment: [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension) is a good starting point. Point to be made clear - I am not affiliated with them neither am I trying to spam... just wanted to share a good resource as asked by OP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In my opinion is not such a Pythonic way for the point of readability counts.

```
sector_epi_states = ['crisis' if sector_g[i] <0 and sector_g[i-1] <0 else ('downturn' if sector_g[i] <0 else 'sucpetible') for i in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest rewriting of your code would be something like:

```
sector_g = [0, -1, 2, 4, 5]
sector_epi_states = [] #sector states

def determine(i, x):
    if x <0 and sector_g[i-1] <0:
        sector_epi_states.append('crisis')
    elif x <0:
        sector_epi_states.append('downturn')
    elif x >0:
        sector_epi_states.append('sucpetible')

[determine(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(sector_g)];
print(sector_epi_states)
```

The main difficulty here is that you check both the "current" value and the previous one, hence the `enumerate` function.

Hope this helps.